# Connect Sails JS to SQL Server EXPRESS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, sql-server-express

I'm learning Sails JS (and NodeJS), and I'm trying to set a connection to SQL Server Express. What I have so far:

A database called `test-project-db` with a table inside called `TestTable1`. It has two columns: `name varchar(20)` and `description varchar(100)`.

A sails project generated with `sails new`, and a model/component made with `sails generate api TestTable1`.

My files:
- api/models/TestTable1.js

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    name: {
      type: 'string',
    },

    description: {
      type: 'string',
    },

  }
};
```

- config/connections.js:

```
sqlserver: {
    adapter : 'sails-sqlserver',
    user    : 'sa',
    password: 'passw',
    host    : 'localhost\\SQLEXPRESS',
    database: 'test-project-db'
  }
```

- config/models.js:

```
module.exports.models = {

  connection: 'sqlserver',

  migrate: 'safe',

};
```

But when I run the server with `sails lift` and go to `localhost:1337/testtable1`, I get the error:

```
(node:15756) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:undefined in 60000ms
(node:15756) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

And, if instead of `sails-sqlserver` I use `sails-mssqlserver`, I get (in the console):

```
{"name":"Sails-MSSqlserver","hostname":"DESKTOP-PMN0K03","pid":15928,"level":30,"msg":"Error in __FIND__: { ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:undefined in 60000ms\n    at Connection.<anonymous> (D:\\Práctica 2\\test-project\\node_modules\\sails-mssqlserver\\node_modules\\mssql\\lib\\tedious.js:378:25)\n    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)\n    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)\n    at Connection.emit (events.js:211:7)\n    at Connection.connectTimeout
(D:\\Práctica 2\\test-project\\node_modules\\sails-mssqlserver\\node_modules\\tedious\\lib\\connection.js:467:12)\n    at ontimeout (timers.js:475:11)\n    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:310:5)\n    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:270:5)\n  name: 'ConnectionError',\n  message: 'Failed to connect to localhost:undefined in 60000ms',\n  code: 'ETIMEOUT' }","time":"2018-01-31T19:00:27.325Z","v":0}
error: Sending 500 ("Server Error") response:
 Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error
ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:undefined in 60000ms
    at Connection.<anonymous> (D:\Práctica 2\test-project\node_modules\sails-mssqlserver\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious.js:378:25)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Connection.connectTimeout (D:\Práctica 2\test-project\node_modules\sails-mssqlserver\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:467:12)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:475:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:310:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:270:5)

Details:  ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:undefined in 60000ms
```

And in the browser:

```
[Error (E_UNKNOWN) Encountered an unexpected error] Details:  ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:undefined in 60000ms
```

Along a 500 error page.

Any idea on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I reckon your issue is with your SQL server config in connections.js, host should be set to the IP plus the port the database is running on. For SQL express this should be port 1433. So set host to 'localhost:1433' or '127.0.0.1:1433'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localhost:undefined` --> The port is undefined because you didn't provide it in the configuration. Add in the `port` attribute into your `sqlserver` connection within `config/connections.js`, and assign it your database server's port.

Side note: learning Sails while learning Node is quite a handful, especially since Sails can look intimidating at first. Just take it piece by piece, and you'll definitely get a hang of it. If you're familiar with MVC frameworks, such as Rails, then Sails will feel right at home.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed it after a while. But I also had another problem, that might be useful for someone. Using `localhost\\SQLEXPRESS` didn't actually work for me. I had to go to SQL Configuration Manager and enable the `127.0.0.1` IP, and then switch `localhost\\SQLEXPRESS` for `127.0.0.1`, while obviously, adding the `port: '1433'` to the dictionary.